# How to determine the sum of the series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to determine the sum of series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^4}{3^k}$

The series converges and I found that: 
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^4}{3^k} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{16}{9} + 3 + \frac{256}{81} ...$

Comment: Hint: apply $x\frac{d}{dx}$ four times to $\sum_{k\ge1}x^k=\frac{x}{1-x}$, then set $x=\frac13$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do expressions of the form $\sum\limits^\infty_{n=1} \frac{n^k}{3^n}$ sum 'nicely'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718785/why-do-expressions-of-the-form-sum-limits-infty-n-1-fracnk3n-sum-n). See also [Summation of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^a}{b^n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439062) and [How to compute sums like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^a}{b^n} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090184).

Comment: No I shouldn't use derivatives to solve that

Comment: Did someone not tell you to use derivatives? That’s the only method I know.

Comment: Could you explain how to use derivatives in this case?

Answer (score 0):

(i) Use a recursive method or Stirling numbers(basically the same thing) to write $k^4$ as a lonear combination of falling powers $$ak^{(4)}+bk^{(3)}+ck^{(2)}+dk^{(1)}$$(ii) write  $$(1/3)^k=(-3/2)\Delta(1/3)^k$$(iii)Sum the terms from $k=1 \space \text {to} k=m$ by applying summation by parts 4 times to reduce to a geometric series. $$\text{(iv)Take the limit as } m \rightarrow \infty$$